# Ionic DateTime error: Cannot read property 'toISOString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, frontend

I want to display the current date as a default value,is not working if I use the formControlName but I need to use the formControlName.

Here is my HTML file

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary"> Start date </ion-label>
    <ion-datetime [value]="startDate.toISOString()" formControlName="startDate" required></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  <div id="startDateErrorMessage" *ngIf="newProjForm.controls['startDate'].invalid &(newProjForm.controls['startDate'].dirty || newProjForm.controls['startDate'].touched)">
    <span class="error ion-padding" *ngIf="newProjForm.controls['startDate'].errors.required"> Date is required </span>
  </div>
```

and here is my TS file

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
selector: 'app-new-project',
templateUrl: './new-project.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./new-project.page.scss'],
})
export class NewProjectPage implements OnInit {
newProjForm: FormGroup;
startDate: Date = new Date();
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private alertCtrl: AlertController) { }
ngOnInit() {
this.newProjForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  startDate: ['' ,[Validators.required]]
}); 
}
}
```

when I compile the project I'm getting this errors

"***ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toISOString' of undefined***"

"***TypeError: Cannot read property 'toISOString' of undefined***"

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: It means your value is coming as undefined. You can put a truthify check and avoid this error. You can access properties on undefined. startDate.toISOString() startDate seems to be undefined here.

Comment: To set the initial value in a form builder object, don't use [value] in the html template. You can replace the '' with the initial value of the field like:   startDate: [(new Date()).toISOString(), [Validators.required]]

Comment: Thanks @C.Gäking now is working :)

Comment: Fine ;-) I'll write it as an answer again so that you can accept it, ok? I would be pleased

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the initial value in a form builder object, don't use [value] in the html template. You can replace the '' with the initial value of the field like:

```
this.newProjForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  startDate: [(new Date()).toISOString(), [Validators.required]] –
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Error due to incorrect time display. The answer you're looking for:

// html:

```
<ion-datetime cancelText="отмена" doneText="Готово" [(ngModel)]="today" displayFormat="D MMM YYYY H:mm"
min="{{min_data}}" max="{{max_data}}" value="2021-11-15T11:00Z" monthShortNames="Январь, Февраль, Март, Апрель, Май, Июнь, Июль, Август, Сентябрь, Октябрь, Ноябрь, Декабрь">
</ion-datetime>
```

// ts:

```
today: any
min_data = ''
max_data = ''

pad(s, width, character) {
    return new Array(width - s.toString().length + 1).join(character) + s;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.today = new Date()
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = 5 // increase by 5 days from today
    this.today.setDate(this.today.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd)
    this.min_data = this.today.getFullYear()+'-'+this.pad(this.today.getMonth() + 1, 2, '0')+'-'+this.pad(this.today.getDate(), 2, '0')
    this.max_data = (this.today.getFullYear()+1)+'-'+this.pad(this.today.getMonth() + 1, 2, '0')+'-'+this.pad(this.today.getDate(), 2, '0')
    this.today = this.today.getFullYear()+'-'+this.pad(this.today.getMonth() + 1, 2, '0')+'-'+this.pad(this.today.getDate(), 2, '0') + ' 18:00'
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).